# Good Idea to do Spring Validation in Domain Objects Builder?

Tags: java, spring, validation

I am writing some helper code to add builders to my domain model using the Builder Pattern.  I have the basic portion of the code built, but I want to added another build method that will validate the newly built object.  I envision this new method would accept a class to match up with the groups in my bean validation.  Therefore, when I get the object back from the builder I know it is a valid object for the state I want.  I have two questions concerning this approach.

First, does this sound like a good approach?  I have not seen anything on the net about doing this, but I think it would be a good idea to have it in the builder.

Next question, What is a good way to get a validator into the builder?  Should I try to auotwire it in or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the builder pattern is a nice way to construct objects, so it should work well for your purposes. You said you want to add *another build method*. Is this implying that you would have 2 build methods - one that validates and one that doesn't? I would only have one method so you can be sure your object validates.

For how to validate, the Spring docs discuss validating  using JSR-303 http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html

Just something to keep in mind as you're building a Spring app. Consider if grails might be something of interest to you. One part of it is domain object validation and it has capabilities to build objects for testing that will validate. Obviously you would want to use more features than just that if you're going to use grails, but just wanted to note it.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about having two methods, one that would blindly build the object and another that would build it and then run validate on it.  I like the idea of just having the validate method.  if you are going to build an object you should know what valid state you want it to reflect.

Comment: As for the validation code, I am familiar with using the `@validated` annotation and I have used it in my method signatures to validate object against specific validation groups.  I tried to use `@autowired` for the validator in the domain object, but that did not work.  In some way it seems wrong to use `@Autowired` in the domain object builder.  I guess the next option is look at creating a validator from scratch.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Why does `@Autowired` seem wrong here? If you want to be able to mock it out for testing or to change the type of validator that is being used, then use autowiring.

Comment: I had a hunch that Spring might not allow it.  I did some research and found that `@Autowired` only applies to Spring beans.  Since these are simple domain objects with `@entity` tags, I don't think they qualify as Spring Beans.  Here is what I was looking at http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html

Comment: I also tried to get the validator to work by manually building the validator, but that did not work.  However, I am giving you the answer, since you did answer the first part.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I misunderstood that these are not beans. You can only use spring annotations/configuration on beans. If you can't make them spring beans, then maybe you could have a `setValidator` method that could be called from a spring bean that does have access to the autowired validator?

Comment: I appreciate your persistence on this question.  I like your idea.  I will add it to the constructor, since I will only have one build method that does validation.  If I am using the builder outside of the Spring context, then I will pass in a null and the build method will not validate.  Thanks!